# Eclipse cant find some of the JUnit files

Tags: eclipse, spring, junit

I have a maven project with spring. And we also have alot of JUnit test classes. We are using Eclipse. Every now and then - quite often actually - eclipse shows some (not all) of the test classes as red... Claiming it cant find imports. Looking at Eclipse error log, I can see alot of these error messages (but for different test-classes ofc).

What is happening? My collegue who works with the same project does not get this error. We are using Eclipse Juno SR2.

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: File not found: C:\xxx\target\test-classes\com\yyy\vet\zzz\service\TradeWashTest.class.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.Policy.error(Policy.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.LocalFile.openInputStream(LocalFile.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.read(FileSystemResourceManager.java:797)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getContents(File.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.util.Util.getResourceContentsAsByteArray(Util.java:1132)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.IncrementalImageBuilder.writeClassFileCheck(IncrementalImageBuilder.java:888)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.IncrementalImageBuilder.writeClassFileContents(IncrementalImageBuilder.java:830)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.writeClassFile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:857)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.acceptResult(AbstractImageBuilder.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:510)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.IncrementalImageBuilder.compile(IncrementalImageBuilder.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.IncrementalImageBuilder.build(IncrementalImageBuilder.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.buildDeltas(JavaBuilder.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:726)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\dev\xxx\target\test-classes\com\yyy\vet\zzz\service\TradeWashTest.class (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.LocalFile.openInputStream(LocalFile.java:368)
    ... 26 more
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be in the jars dependencies (especially if you're using mocks). You need to perform two steps to figure out what the problem is:

1.Run unit tests using maven (in case it works you can go to step2);
2. Look into jars order in the Eclipse (projects setting-> java build path-> order and settings).

In case you said that it works for your colleague you need to compare order of your jars  with jar's order of you colleague